# Group/Portfolio constraints in a linear programming

Tags: r, linear-programming

I am doing a portfolio optimization as a linear programming problem. I have 500 stocks, and i want - with a set of constraints - to maximize my decision variable.

From the code below i get a portfolio suggestion.. but I need one more constraint: The portfolio can min have 20 different stocks. How do i introduce that constraint?

I have updated the code a bit.. but i cant get it to work... from the code below i would expect to get a portfolio of 7 stocks.. the idea behind the code is the answer below

```
df_temp <-temp <- data.frame(stock_number= seq(1:50), OPT= runif(50), 
                   ctrl=1, alt=0)
df_temp_1 <- data.frame(stock_number= paste("a",seq(1:50)), OPT= 0, 
                        ctrl=0, alt=1)
df_temp <- rbind(df_temp, df_temp_1)

require(lpSolveAPI)


example <- make.lp(1,NROW(df_temp))

row.add.mode(example,"on")
add.constraint(example,xt=df_temp$ctrl ,type="=",rhs=1,indices=c(1: nrow(df_temp)))
add.constraint(example,xt=df_temp$alt ,type="=",rhs=7,indices=c(1: nrow(df_temp)))

for (i in 1:50)
{
  add.constraint(example,df_temp$ctrl[i] ,type="<=",rhs=0.2,indices=c(i))
  add.constraint(example,df_temp$alt[i+50]*999 - df_temp$ctrl[i],type=">=",rhs=0,indices=c(i))
  add.constraint(example,df_temp$alt[i+50]-df_temp$ctrl[i] ,type="<=",rhs=0,indices=c(i))
}

row.add.mode(example,"off")

set.type(example,c(1:50), "real" )
set.type(example,c(51:100), "binary" )
         
lp.control(example, sense="max")
set.objfn(example,obj=df_temp$OPT )
solve(example)
df_temp$PFW <- get.variables(example)

df_temp
```

Comment: CVXR may be an easier tool to express portfolio models. It works at a higher level, so you can express things more naturally. In addition, it will allow you to form quadratic models (often used to model risk).

Answer (score 2):

If x(i) = the number of stocks suggested for stock i, where i ranges from 1 to 500, then you need auxiliary binary variables that will equal 1 if stock i is suggested, and 0 if not.  So you could introduce the binary variables y(i) from i = 1 to 500, and add in the constraint set

M * y(i) >= x(i)

y(i) <= x(i)

Where M is a large number.  These constraints say that if we aren’t buying stock i, (so x(i) = 0) then y(i) has to be 0.  If we are buying stock i, (so x(i) > 0) then y(i) has to be 1.

Then you can use these new variables to satisfy your new single constraint

sum(all y(i)) >= 20

Note: try the Operations Research site for these types of questions about linear programming modeling

Comment: I cant get this to work.. i see the logic, but RsolveAPI returns error that xt is and indicies are not the same length... can u provide the coding example?

Comment: Does anyone know how to translate this into RsolveAPI code?